# How do I use a dropdownlistfor on these objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to reference a dropdown from an object that looks like this

```
public virtual List<Administrator> AuthorizedAdministrators { get; set; }
public int SelectedAuthorizedAdministrators { get; set; }
```

I am referencing like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedAuthorizedAdministrators, new 
SelectList(Model.AuthorizedAdministrators.Select(x => new { Value = x.Id, Text = x.Username }),
 "Value", "Text"), Model.SelectedAuthorizedAdministrators)
```

The error I get is

```
 c:\STI\Portals\STI.Network.Web\Views\FinancialInstitutions\Create.cshtml(102): error CS0012: 
The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not 
referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Collections, 
Version=4.0.0.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

How do I solve this error? Am I referencing this model correctly in my view?

Comment: Did you try adding a reference to `System.Collections`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below, I think it may helps you.

Please change the drop down code like below as simple

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedAuthorizedAdministrators, new SelectList(Model.AuthorizedAdministrators, "Id", "Username "))
```

Comment: If this code help full to you, please click the tick mark. That will helps others to find the answer while on searching